# Is automated testing possible for Drupal sites ( TestNG and Selenium)?

Tags: drupal, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver, testng

I saw that Drupal 7 includes some kind of testing framework (I haven't tried it out yet since my existing sites are still in Drupal 6 and likely won't migrate any time soon). I want to test Drupal sites now,

1. Are there any problems if I use TestNG and selenium webdriver for testing Drupal sites?
2. If so what are the problems?
3. What are the best testing frameworks for testing Drupal sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. A drupal site is just HTML like any other site
2. N/A
3. Not a question for SO. Find which one works best for you